# Compile error when using lambda functions in the header file

Tags: c++, lambda

I've seen a (weird) compile error in my code when trying to learn and use lambda functions. I've spent some time debugging it but still don't know what's wrong. So I have a header file named `config.h`, which is like

```
namespace config {
    ...
    const int kNumPeriodsPerMove = [&] () {
        const double time_nbr_disc = kSizeSlotHello * kNumSlotsHelloPerNbrDisc;
        const double time_data_tx = kSizeSlotData * kNumSlotsDataPerDataTx;
        const double time_epoch = time_nbr_disc + time_data_tx;
        const int num_periods_per_move = ceil(kTimeBtwMoves / time_epoch);
        return num_periods_per_move;
    };
    ...
}
```

where variables in the form of `k*` like `kSizeSlotHello` are all `const` variables that have been defined before and also within `config`. When I compile I have the error messages:

```
config.h:183:5: error: invalid user-defined conversion from ‘config::<lambda()>’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
 };
 ^
config.h:175:41: note: candidate is: config::<lambda()>::operator int (*)()() const <near match>
const int kNumPeriodsPerMove = [&] () {
                                     ^
config.h:175:41: note:   no known conversion from ‘int (*)()’ to ‘int’
```

I also used lambda functions in other places like `const int kNumSlots = [&] (double (*f)(double)) {...} (f);` which does not have any compile error. I'm very curious about what the problem is. Thanks.

Comment: You probably wanted to call that lambda? Add a `()` right before the `;` A lambda expression `[&]() { /* ... *] }` yields a so-called *function object*, that is an object of class type which you can call just like a function. Without that call, it's just an object of class type which cannot be converted to `int`.

Comment: @dyp Damn. You're right. I've been so dumb not to add a `()` before the `;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By doing that:

```
const int kNumPeriodsPerMove = [&] () {
    // your code here
    return num_periods_per_move;
};
```

You are not actually executing it.
Instead, you are creating a `lambda function` instance that cannot be converted to `int`.
So, the error is meaningful.

Instead, you should have:

```
auto fn = [&] () {
    // your code here
    return num_periods_per_move;
};

int kNumPeriodsPerMove = fn();
```

Or even that (more concise):

```
int kNumPeriodsPerMove = ([&] () {
    // your code here
    return num_periods_per_move;
})();
```

That said, one could argue about the fact that to use the lambda this way does not make much sense and you should maybe revise that part of code.